# vs code print after code is done?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
import time 
for i in range(100):
     time.sleep(0.1)
     print("sleeping is happening")
```

I think it will print the string every 0.1 seconds, but actually it prints the string 100 times on the output client after the code is done.

The answer is a little different **(python version 3.5)**:

following is not useful

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

and

```
print("sleeping is happening", flush = True)
```

is corret.

Comment: Need more details

Comment: do you need to flush the print calls perhaps

Comment: [How to flush output of print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function) 
There is a solution in this question . but not the top one .
```print("sleeping is continuing", flush=True)```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Did the answers in the question above answer your problem?

Comment: The solution is about **flush**, thank you very much!!!
```print("sleeping is continuing", flush=True)``` is the right answer. but I don't understand why there is no need in jupyter notebook...

Comment: Because Jupyter internally uses unbuffered output. You can also set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` environment variable to always have your stdout unbuffered, but there are performance implications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There so many things to learn.....